# Running my eclipse plugin end up with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle

I am trying to develop an eclipse plugin that adds an action to the right click menu.
I have created a java project with plugin.xml, and added the related java class that invokes an action on java files(ActionDelegate).
When i run this code as "eclipse application", the class is being invoked and everything works as i expected.

The problem is when i convert this project to "plug-in project" via eclipse in order to create plug-in, and run it again as "eclipse application", then i get ClassNotFoundException on the java class i have created.

On the process of converting this project to "plug-in project" eclipse adds a MANIFEST.MF, which related to OSGI bundles.
If i remove this file - all works well, and if i add the MANIFEST.MF file - again i get the above ClassNotFoundException, so probably there is something wrong with the MANIFEST.MF and the project representation as plug-in.

Also, when i try to export this plug-in as "Deployable plug-ins and fragments" and install it into host Repository i get the following error:
Could not find the exported unit with id: MyReloader version: 1.0.0.201304210902.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it is an eclipse version issue, or jre used.
once i switched to a different jre, it worked well