# ClassNotFoundException when running my plugins in a new eclipse configuration instance

Tags: eclipse, plugins, classnotfoundexception

I am running two eclipse plugins that I developped. These plugins are successfully imported to the new workspace within the persisted container Library. So far everything is OK, the problems started while I was trying to test my plugins : 
1) I couldn't neither gain from eclipse's text auto-completion to navigate the classes of my plugins or their methods
2) When I run this test I get a classNotfoundException here is the error :

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Trying to remedy to this problem, I applied the solution proposed by eran_levi : "[Running my eclipse plugin end up with ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128453/running-my-eclipse-plugin-end-up-with-classnotfoundexception)" but it didn't work for me. 
Any sort of help is really appreciated.
Thank you in Advance !!!

Comment: Doesn't eclipse report any errors for the 2 plugins?  What do you mean "persisted container Library"?  Are the project listed at the root of your workspace?

Comment: I wanted to play clever and I didn't export all the plugins while defining the running configuration (only my two plugins and some equinox plugins). When I imported all the plugins everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to play clever and I didn't export all the plugins while defining the running configuration (only my two plugins and some equinox plugins). When I imported all the plugins everything worked well.